# optional field for @joincolumn annotation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, joincolumn

I have to use below syntax for one column in my model class

```
@JoinColumn(name = "Username", referencedColumnName = "name", optional = true)
private user username;
```

But I am getting compilation error at "`optional`", I am Using `persistence-api-1.0.jar`, Please suggest me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for 'nullable' instead of 'optional'.  'optional' is not a valid field in JoinColumn.  Here's the API which shows the fields available on javax.persistence.JoinColumn: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html